# Sinusoidal regression line with scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I tried the following to find a sine regression but I am not able to draw a sine curve. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def sinfunc(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.sin(b * (x - np.radians(c)))+d

year=np.arange(0,24,2)
population=np.array([10.2,11.1,12,11.7,10.6,10,10.6,11.7,12,11.1,10.2,10.2])

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sinfunc, year, population, p0=None)

x_data = np.linspace(0, 25, num=100)

plt.scatter(year,population,label='Population')
plt.plot(x_data, sinfunc(x_data, *popt), 'r-',label='Fitted function')
plt.title("Year vs Population")
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Population')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The TI-nspire shows y=sin(0.58x-1)+11

[image]

### Update

If I use `p0=[1,0.4,1,5]` it works well. But shouldn't it be automatic?

Comment: I think the problem is that your `b` parameter turns out to be almost zero, so the fit is dominated by the `d` term. I was able to get something close to the second answer by providing a reasonable guess value, `p0=[1, 0.5, 1, 10]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you are doing "wrong" is passing `p0=None` to `curve_fit()`.

All fitting methods really, really require initial values. Unfortunately,  `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` has the completely unjustifiable option of allowing you to not set initial values and silently (not even a warning!!) making the absurd guess that all values have initial values of 1.0.  It turns out that for your problem these impossible-to-justify-and-broken-by-design initial values are so bad that the fit fails to find a good answer.  This is not uncommon. `curve_fit` is lying to you that `p0=None` is acceptable, and you are believing that lie.

The solution is to recognize that the offset is obviously around 11 and use `p0=[1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 11.0]`.

You might consider using `lmfit` (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/). for this problem (disclaimer: I am a lead author).  `lmfit` has a `Model` class for curve-fitting that has several useful features that might be useful here (not that `curve_fit` cannot solve this problem -- it can). With `lmfit`, your fit might look like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model

def sinfunc(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.sin(b*(x - c)) + d

year=np.arange(0,24,2)
population=np.array([10.2,11.1,12,11.7,10.6,10,
                     10.6,11.7,12,11.1,10.2,10.2])

# build model from your model function  
model  = Model(sinfunc)

# create parameters (with initial values!). Note that parameters 
# are named from the argument names of your model function
params = model.make_params(a=1, b=0.5, c=0.5, d=11.0)

# you can set min/max for any parameter to put bounds on the values
params['a'].min = 0
params['c'].min = -np.pi
params['c'].max = np.pi

# do the fit to your data with those parameters
result = model.fit(population, params, x=year)

# print out report of fit statistics and parameter values+uncertainties
print(result.fit_report())

# plot data and fit result
plt.scatter(year,population,label='Population')
plt.plot(year, result.best_fit, 'r-',label='Fitted function')
plt.title("Year vs Population")
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Population')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This will print out a report of

```
[[Model]]
    Model(sinfunc)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 26
    # data points      = 12
    # variables        = 4
    chi-square         = 0.00761349
    reduced chi-square = 9.5169e-04
    Akaike info crit   = -80.3528861
    Bayesian info crit = -78.4132595
[[Variables]]
    a:  1.00465520 +/- 0.01247767 (1.24%) (init = 1)
    b:  0.57528444 +/- 0.00198556 (0.35%) (init = 0.5)
    c:  1.80990367 +/- 0.03823815 (2.11%) (init = 0.5)
    d:  11.0250780 +/- 0.00925246 (0.08%) (init = 11)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(b, c) =  0.812
    C(b, d) =  0.245
    C(c, d) =  0.234
```

and produce a plot of 
[image]

But, again: the problem is that you were suckered into believing that `p0=None` is a reasonable use of `curve_fit()`.

Comment: Thanks, Newville. It is good to hear. So basically you are saying that scipy.optimize.curve_fit() sacks. Are there any better way to do it?

Comment: Well, I think curve_fit is *mostly* good, and am very much in favor of and appreciative of scipy. I think that allowing `p0=None` is a very bad feature and trips up many people exactly in the way it tripped you up.   You might consider using the `lmfit` library (I am a lead author) for this problem (I'll update answer), but `curve_fit` should work for your case.